# Delete a user together with his posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models - User and Post. User `has_many :posts` and Post `belongs_to :user`. I want to delete user's posts automatically when the user is deleted. How can I do this? I am very new to ruby..

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @user = User.find_by(id:params[:id])
    @user.posts
    @user.destroy
  end
end
```

I've tried the code above, but still only the user is deleted, not his posts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@user.posts` only retrieves posts collection for given user. If you want to destroy such associated entries, use destroy_all: `@user.posts.destroy_all`. It's not the answer and not the right way in your situation, but it can be useful in rails console, for example

Comment: Please, add really used rails version to tags. I suppose, your app is on Rails 5, and it can't be on Rails 3 at the same time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `dependent` option for `has_many`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

With it you delete only a needed user, his posts are destroyed automagically

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @user.destroy
end
```

Please, read more about it in [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many)